# Get the first value of result of LookupSet if not null in SSRS for Dynamic 365

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm

I'm writing a report for Microsoft Dynamics 365 Version 1612 (8.2.2.113) which uses the following expression:

```
=IIF(LookupSet("Test", Fields!new_product_name.Value, Fields!new_product_code.Value, "Test_DataSet").Length = 0,
     "",
     LookupSet("Test", Fields!new_product_name.Value, Fields!new_product_code.Value, "Test_DataSet")(0)
 )
```

The idea is to return the code of first product with name as "Test", and return blank if there is no match.

However, because IIF in SSRS does not short-circuited, even if there is no match, it will still try to get the first (index = 0) element from LookupSet and then throw an error.

How can I archive what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you need is the first result, then you should be able to just use `Lookup`. Have you tried that?

`Lookup` returns the first result if there are any results, or `Nothing` if there are no results.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed my problem. But what if I need more that the first result, let say display the first and second code if there are more than 2 results and Nothing if there are 1 or no result?

Comment: In that situation it would most likely be better to alter you dataset if possible. But if that is not possible, you may be able to use a combination of `Join` and `Split`, maybe along with some regex logic so that you do not have to reference the `LookupSet` result array elements directly, but I have not tested that so I'm not exactly sure how those functions react to `Nothing`. The main issue (and the reason for your initial error) is that you are directly referencing the 1st result of the `LookupSet` results, which if there are no results, will throw an error.