# Selecting a First() non-null value in SSRS with a visual basic expression

Tags: vba, reporting-services

I am used to using `First()` in a VB expression in SSRS in order to select the first value in a dataset. 
Example: 
    `First(Fields!Month.Value, "datasetName")`

Now I am trying to select the first non-null value. Any hints on how to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46949286/get-the-first-value-of-result-of-lookupset-if-not-null-in-ssrs-for-dynamic-365 . Hope it adds something to your answer.

Comment: Hi Krunal, thanks voor your answer. As far as I understand this `Lookup` function, what it does is compare a source expression to a destination expression in order to return a third expression ("result"). So this only works when comparing two fields under the condition that they are equal. Am I right? Can I also use this if I don't need a condition to be true?